# Competitive programming: Good Subsets problem

Tags: algorithms, arrays, mathematical-programming, subsequences

An array of length K is called good if for each subarray of the array, the sum of the subarray is not divisible by K+1. You are given an array A of length N. Find the number of subsequences of length B of array A which are good. Since the answer can be large, return it modulo 10^9+7.

**Constraints:**

- 1 <= N <= 1000
- 1 <= A[i] <= 100000
- 1 <= B <=10

**Time limit: 1 sec**

**Input format:** The first line contains an integer N denoting the number of elements in an array. Second-line contains N space-separated integers representing array elements. The third line contains an integer B

*Sample Input 1:*

```
4

2 3 4 5

1
```

*Sample Output 1:*

```
2
```

*Explanation:* Here B=1, so any good subsequence should not have any subarray divisible by 2 (2 because B+1 = 2). Therefore, 2 possible subsequences are {3} and {5}. We cannot consider {3,5} because the sum of 3+5 is divisible by 2. Also the same reason for other ignored subsequences.

Sample Input 2:

```
3

3 5 4

4
```

Sample Output 2:

```
3
```

*Explaination:* Possible subsequences are {3},{4},{3,4} because no subset of these subsequence is divisible by 5 (here B=4)

I came up with a recursive approach but it was getting TLE (Time limit Exceed).

Comment: [Programming is off topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please state the origin of contents you present, but did not create. Use of a *block quote* facilitates telling such from the rest of your post.

Comment: @greybeard actually it was from a company coding test which was conducted in my college. So there is no link or screenshot.

Comment: Since you have a recursive algorithm, have you tried dynamic programming?

Comment: @D.W. I didn't get how to apply dynamic programming on this.

Comment: We have a set of resources on that subject: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info.  Please follow the systematic approach shown there, and then [edit] your question to show what progress you've made and at what stage you got stuck.